# how to get value from same class

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have some input fields which have the same class, dynamically generated by an ajax request. When I try to get 2nd or 3rd... input field value I am getting the value of the 1st input field.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="number" name="product_quantity" class="form-control Product_quantity" value="11"/>

<input type="button" onclick="updateQuantity(41)" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update">

<input type="number" name="product_quantity" class="form-control Product_quantity" value="9"/>

<input type="button" onclick="updateQuantity(42)" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update">

<input type="number" name="product_quantity" class="form-control Product_quantity" value="5"/>

<input type="button" onclick="updateQuantity(43)" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update">
```

**JS:**

```
function updateQuantity(id){
    var url = "{{ url('/api/carts/update') }}";
    var  product_quantity = $('.product_quantity').val();
    var cart_id = id;

    $.post(
    url,
    {
        product_quantity: product_quantity,
        id:cart_id
    }
    ).done(function(data){
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        if(data.status == "success"){
            alertify.set('notifier','position', 'top-center');
            alertify.success('Item updated successfully !!');
            $("#totalItems").html(data.totalItems);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
alert(document.getElementsByClassName("Product_quantity")[0].value);
alert(document.getElementsByClassName("Product_quantity")[1].value);
alert(document.getElementsByClassName("Product_quantity")[2].value);
```

```html
<input type="number" name="product_quantity" class="form-control Product_quantity" value="11"/>

<input type="button" onclick="updateQuantity(41)" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update">

<input type="number" name="product_quantity" class="form-control Product_quantity" value="9"/>

<input type="button" onclick="updateQuantity(42)" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update">

<input type="number" name="product_quantity" class="form-control Product_quantity" value="5"/>

<input type="button" onclick="updateQuantity(43)" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
       function updateQuantity(id){
            var url = "{{ url('/api/carts/update') }}";
            var  product_quantity = $('#product_quantity'+id).val();
            alert(product_quantity);

                   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--  You should give id for each input types like below -->

        <input type="number" name="product_quantity" id="product_quantity41" class="form-control Product_quantity" value="11"/>
        <input type="button" onclick="updateQuantity(41)"  class="btn btn-primary" value="Update">
        <input type="number" name="product_quantity" id="product_quantity42" class="form-control Product_quantity" value="9"/>
        <input type="button" onclick="updateQuantity(42)" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update">
       <input type="number" name="product_quantity" id="product_quantity43" class="form-control Product_quantity" value="5"/>
        <input type="button" onclick="updateQuantity(43)" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update">
```